# How can I confirm if/what Windows Defender is submitting to Microsoft through autosubmission?

Tags: windows-10, windows-defender

I'm seeing large uploads taking place at night and am suspecting that it might be windows Defender submitting files. How can I confirm that?

Comment: May be [WireShark](https://www.wireshark.org/) will help. Or any network packet capture tool.

Comment: @Biswa  thanks. That's a little inconvenient since whatever is happening is late at night. I was hoping for an event viewer log or submission history but don't see specific events about file submission.

Comment: I'm going to guess that you can't. When dealing with virus samples, its standard practice to encrypt them, so that their code cannot be executed accidentally, and to defang parser attacks on the software reading them.

Comment: @FrankThomas Thanks. So far, I don't see ANY malicious activity on the system or traces of malware.  I do use the system as a file server so I'm guessing that when I transfer largish files over, it triggers a background task later.  We'll see how things go.

Comment: I would not expect WD to upload any kind of non-executable file, so its unlikely to transfer your large files (though it will scan them locally on read/write). Files are submitted to their online analysis tools when they are previously unknown, or are otherwise abnormal, so MS can analyze them and determine whether a signature should be added or heuristics tweaked to deal with a new kind of threat.

Comment: I'm reluctant to close this question because I really WOULD like to know if there's a log or way to tell if Windows defender has a log mechanism for this operation.  But in the interest of updating in case that doesn't happen, my immediate issue is resolved.  It turned out to be a video screensaver that was streaming in the background (as part of a home theater PC when it wasn't in use). I was able to tell by enabling some deep-packet inspection on my router and review traffic log times.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be logged in the Windows Event Viewer.

Launch the Event Viewer, then in the tree widget on the left, expand `Applications and Services Logs > Microsoft > Windows > Windows Defender > Operational`. The contents of each sub-tree took several seconds to load for me. Then, in the list of events in the middle, you can sift through to find events like this one:

```
Microsoft Defender Antivirus has uploaded a file for further analysis.
    Filename: C:\Users\Tim\Documents\AProgramThatIWroteMyself.exe
    Sha256: [...]
```

I imagine you should be able to create a filter for these via the `Filename` Data property in the XML:

```xml
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  [...]
  <EventData>
    [...]
    <Data Name="Filename">C:\Users\Tim\Documents\AProgramThatIWroteMyself.exe</Data>
    [...]
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

...but the filter and custom view tools seem pretty opaque to me at a glance and I haven't been able to figure this step out.